# Fortran `write (*, '(3G24.16)')` error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, math, fortran, gfortran

I have a Fortran file that must write these complicated numbers, basically I can't change these numbers:

File name: complicatedNumbers.f

```
      implicit none

      write (*,'(3G24.16)')  0.4940656458412465-323, 8.651144521298990, 495.6336980600139
      end
```

It's then run with `gfortran -o outa complicatedNumbers.f` on my Ubuntu, but this error comes up:

```
Error: Expected expression in WRITE statement at (1)
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the complicated numbers because there are no errors if I change the three complicated numbers into simple numbers such as `11.11, 22.2, 33.3`.

This is actually a stripped-down version of a complex Fortran file that contains many variables and links to other files. So ideally, the 3G24.16 should not be changed.

**What does the 3G24.16 mean?**

**How can I fix it so that I can ultimately print out these numbers with ./outa?**

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing syntactically wrong in the snippet you've shown us. However, your use of a file name with the suffix `.f` makes me think that the compiler is assuming that your code is written in fixed form.  That is the usual default behaviour of gfortran. If that is the case it probably truncates that line at about the last `,` which means that the compiler sees

```
write (*,'(3G24.16)')  0.4940656458412465-323, 8.651144521298990,
```

and raises the complaint you have shared with us.  Either join us in the 21st Century and switch to free form source files, change `.f` to `.f90` and see what fun ensues, or continue the line correctly with some character in column 6 of the next line.

As to what `3G24.16` means, refer to your favourite Fortran reference material under the heading of *data edit descriptors*, in particular the *g data edit descriptor*.

Oh, and if my bandying about of the terms *fixed form source* and *free form source* bamboozles you, read about them in your favourite Fortran reference material too.

Answer (score 0):

Three errors in your program :

- as you clearly use the Fortran fixed format, instructions are limited to 72 characters (132 in free format)
- the number 0.4940656458412465-323 is probably not correctly written. The exponent character is missing. Try 0.4940656458412465D-323 instead. Here Fortran computes the substraction => 0.4940656458412465-323 is replaced by -322.505934354159. Notice that I propose the exponent D (double precision). Writing 0.4940656458412465E-323 is inaccurate because, for a single precision number, the minimum value for the exponent is -127.
- other numbers should have an exponent D0 too because, in single precision, the number of significant digits do not exceed 6.

Possible correction, always in fixed format :

```
  implicit none

  write (*,'(3G24.16)')  0.4940656458412465D-323,
 &                       8.651144521298990d0, 
 &                       495.6336980600139d0
  end
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure your 'correction' which produces `0.4940656458412465D-323` is correct, it is likely to produce a compiler warning to the effect that the result is a denormalised number.  There's nothing unusual about the expression `0.4940656458412465-323`

Comment: Also, wrt your first point, instructions are not limited to 72 characters, The instructions on fixed form lines must lie in columns `[7,72]` leaving only 66 useful character positions for instructions. But instructions can be continued across up to 19 continuation lines.  I guess that means that an instruction is limited to `20*66 = 1320` characters.

Comment: About "instruction" you are right : I should write "line" instead. The expression 0.4940656458412465-323 is not a number : it has probably been obtained in writing a number using a format with a two small space for the exponent : so the character E has disappeared.

Comment: When I run my correction program, I get as result :  0.4940656458412465-323   8.651144521298990       495.6336980600139 : the character E has disappeared !

Comment: Indeed `0.4940656458412465-323` is not a number, but the result of the subtraction IS a number and Fortran happily accepts that sort of expression in `write` statements.  But rather than you and me arguing over this and that, I wonder what OP intended to write there.

Comment: If you write a value with a three-digit exponent using a format that doesn't have an explicit number of exponent digits, such as E23.15E3, then the exponent letter is removed. This is in the standard. While such numbers are accepted during formatted input, as discussed above, in source code it looks like a subtraction.